# How can I concatenate the string that I'm using to define this label text

Tags: ios, objective-c

this seems like it is probably dead simple to somebody but I'm stuck.

I have this little app that picks a random thing from an array of things and then displays it to the user in the form of a question.

```
NSLog(@"How about %@?", theThing);


// How About...

self.theThingLabel.text = theThing;

//How do I add a question mark to the end of that string
```

in the code above the NSLog string works just like I want the label to work. I take care of the "how about" part as a string above the displayed result, but I can't figure out how to add that question mark .. something like theThing+"?"

I tried a bunch of stuff but instead of getting lucky I got warned by xcode over and over.

Comment: Use theThing = [theThing stringByAppendingString:@"?"];

Comment: Look at `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Is there a way to do it without modifying the value of my variable, I want to use it without the questionmark later ... I think I'll make a new variable in the format you are suggesting. Thanks!!.. trying it onw

Comment: you can directly set the appended string to `theThingLabel`, without assigning to `theThing`

Comment: This is pretty basic. Please refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

self.theThingLabel.text = [theThing stringByAppendingString:@" ?"];

Comment: Thanks! I did something pretty similar        NSString *theThingQuestion = [theThing stringByAppendingString:@"?"];

Answer (score 0):

```
self.theThingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How about %@?",theThing];
```

This is very easy

Comment: Thanks! I know it was very easy.. sorry about that. But now I am onto other things without being stuck on something so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  :

```
 self.theThingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How about %@  ?", theThing];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theThing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How about %@?",theThing];

NSLog(@"%@", theThing);

then

self.theThingLabel.text = theThing;
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you!! I did something very similar after I got help in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *what= @"What";
 NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How about %@ ..?", what];
 NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

Hope that helps